# How to retrieve attachment as file URL instead of binary data, using REST API?

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am trying to access attachment content from couchbase lite, using REST api. I want to access attachment (e.g. image file) as file URL instead of binary data.

GET request returns binary stream of attachment content. Here, I want to get URL so that it can be stored and access later or pass around.

As my app is hybrid, Android/iOS + sencha touch, there is requirement which expect file URL at native side (e.g. to play video attachment using native app).

Thanks,
Jayesh

Answer (score 0):

If you send a `HEAD` request to the attachment URL, the iOS version adds a `Location:` response header with the URL of the file. Not sure if the Android version does; if not, you could file an issue requesting it.

Comment: Can you please post a sample code?... I tried but could not get URL in response header. (iOS version)

Comment: I just checked the source code — the `Location` header is only added if the request is `HEAD`, not `GET` (which makes sense, otherwise you'd get the body streamed to you as well.) Sorry for the confusion.